# JQuery Select2 Autocomplete Dropdown with multiple selection

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

Here using JQuery Select 2 Autocomplete Dropdown with multiple selection.

When it is use by single it is working fine,like this

[image: Only one dropdown]

But When it is use by more than one Auto complete Not Working ,like this

[image: More than one dropdown]

```
<div class="col-lg-6" ng-repeat="locationtype in allLocationTypes">
    <b><label ng-bind="locationtype.Type"></label></b>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="LocationMapID" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Location" style="width:100%">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled">--Select Location--</option>
            <option  ng-repeat="location in allLocations | filter :filterLocations(locationtype.ID) " value="{{location.ChildLocationID}}">{{location.ParentLocation + '-' + location.ChildLocation}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The event handlers from jquery-select2 fight the event handlers from the AngularJS framework. How is the code integrating select2 with the AngularJS framework? Have you consided using an AngularJS library like [tag:angular-ui-select], AngularJS-native version of Select2 and Selectize?

Comment: Integrate the Select2 plugin here, https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue before

to resolve this I have set Uniq Id for each select2 box

```
<div class="col-lg-6" ng-repeat="locationtype in allLocationTypes">
    <b><label ng-bind="locationtype.Type"></label></b>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="LocationMapID_{{locationtype.Type}}" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Location" style="width:100%">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled">--Select Location--</option>
            <option  ng-repeat="location in allLocations | filter :filterLocations(locationtype.ID) " value="{{location.ChildLocationID}}">{{location.ParentLocation + '-' + location.ChildLocation}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```